Supabase Error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
I have two tables bands_profiles and bands.
I'm trying to get all bands that a user is part of.
The JS query I've written is
const usersBands = await supabase
    .from("bands_profiles")
    .select("*, bands(*)")
    .eq("profile_id", userResponse.data.user.id);

My expected outcome is to get a response with all my bands_profiles rows with data populated from bands so that when I write usersBands.data[0].name, I get the name for the associated foreign key.
My actual outcome is that I get a message saying more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.
I've only got one row in bands_profiles and bands.


Run the query in psql to see what it returns. 2) Look in the Postgres log to see what the ORM is turning the questi0n construct into. Add answers as text update to question text.

